# Composing new email with same set of recipients (To, Cc, Bcc) from existing email

Tags: gmail

I am on Gmail. I would like to compose a *new email* with the *exact same list of* recipients (to, cc, bcc) from an existing email.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The *easiest* way to do it is simply to "Reply All" on the existing message, delete all of the quoted text and the existing subject, and write a brand new message.

The downside to this method is that it'll include a tracking header in the message that ties back to the original message. Email clients that use that information will indicate the new message is a reply to the original, although it's not. These days, though, I don't know that many email clients use that. Even Google's conversation mode uses the subject line more than the reply headers.